# Getting the list item Permission using Rest Api

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, rest

I'm trying to get the list item permission using restapi in asp.net mvc. i had get the permission using below url

```
https://XXXXX.sharepoint.com/sites/AppDevelopment/PM/Data/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Task')/items(45)/getusereffectivepermissions('LoginName')
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<d:GetUserEffectivePermissions m:type="SP.BasePermissions" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"><d:High m:type="Edm.Int64">2147483647</d:High><d:Low m:type="Edm.Int64">4294967295</d:Low></d:GetUserEffectivePermissions>
```

Code i tried

```
    string requestUrl = string.Format("{0}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('{1}')/items({2})/getusereffectivepermissions('{3}')", siteUrl, listName, id, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(userName));
    string result = RestApi_GetJsonTemp(accesstoken, requestUrl, "application/json; odata=verbose", "application/json; odata=verbose");
    BasePermissions permissionJson = new BasePermissions();
    using (TextReader sr = new StringReader(result))
    {
        JsonReader jsonreader = new JsonReader(sr, null);
        permissionJson.FromJson(jsonreader);

    }
```

how to use this high and low value to know what the permission?

Answer (score 4):

The following example demonstrates how to:

- initialize `SP.BasePermissions` object from `json` object
- determine user roles using [SP.BasePermissions.has(perm) Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee659513%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Example:

```
function getListPermissions(webUrl,listTitle,accountName) 
{
    var endpointUrl = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/getusereffectivepermissions(@u)?@u='" + encodeURIComponent(accountName) + "'";
    return $.getJSON(endpointUrl);
}
```

**Usage**

```
var accountName = 'i:0#.f|membership|jdoe@contoso.onmicrosoft.com'
var listTitle = 'Tasks';
getListPermissions(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,listTitle,accountName)
.done(function(data)
{
    var permissions = new SP.BasePermissions();
    permissions.initPropertiesFromJson(data);
    if (permissions.has(SP.PermissionKind.viewListItems)){
       console.log(String.format('User can access {0} list',listTitle));    
    }
})
.fail(function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

---

**C# version**

Since `getusereffectivepermissions` method returns [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.BasePermissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd964767(v=office.12).aspx) object that consists of the following properties :

- `High` - Specifies the most-significant 32 bits of the
  BasePermissions uint
- `Low` - Specifies the least-significant 32 bits of the
  BasePermissions uint

the following classes have been introduced:

- [BasePermissions.cs](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/6c6077982a417d918887) - contains the method to check permissions
- [PermissionKind.cs](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/eaae8c3ebe2b34c16454) - represent the permission levels

Having said that, below is provided the C# example that demonstrates how to determine user permissions:

```
using (var client = new SPHttpClient(webUri, userName, password))
{
     string endpointUrl = webUri + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/getusereffectivepermissions(@u)?@u='" + Uri.EscapeDataString(accountName) + "'";
     var data = client.GetJson(endpointUrl);
     var permissions = BasePermissions.ParseFromJson(data);
     if (permissions.Has(PermissionKind.ViewListItems)){
                Console.WriteLine("User {0} can access {1} list",accountName,listTitle);    
     }
 }
```

where `SPHttpClient class` is a Http client for SharePoint Online , follow [Consume SharePoint Online REST service using .NET](http://blog.vgrem.com/2015/04/04/consume-sharepoint-online-rest-service-using-net/) article for a details.

Comment: This is in jsom. i need in csom?

Comment: This is not neither JSOM nor CSOM, this is **REST** API using JavaScript. I'm confused with your question, could you clarify your question?

Comment: Your saying about SP.BasePermissions that is Client Side. I need in Server Side.

Comment: Server Side or **Client Side Object Model** ? I'm still confused.. Can you explain why your question is tagged with REST but at the same time you are asking about Server Side?

Comment: SP.BasePermissions() is a Javascript right?

Comment: i'm not find InitPropertiesFromJson method in BasePermissions

Comment: I would recommend you to get acquainted with [Choose the right API set in SharePoint 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164060.aspx) article to get familiar with APIs and then ask. I  guess you need  to consume **SharePoint REST API** in C#, isn't it?

Comment: yes. How can i process the above xml to get list permission in c#?

Comment: The answer has been updated